# Try Sencha Touch examples locally

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, sencha-touch, extjs

Can one download the source code and try out the examples for local testing . E.g. I am trying to preview the example on my iPad (after downloading locally), but am unable to see anything;

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/oreilly/

I know for commecrial use, we need to pay, But just need to try it out first...

Answer (score 4):

Actually as far as I understand, you don't need to pay for commercial use either for Sencha Touch. If you want a support plan, then you need to pay, otherwise the license is free (See the top of [the pricing page][1] which says "Free license!".

To view the examples:

1. Download the source code from http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/download/1.1.0/
2. Unzip the file (e.g. /home/username/sencha-touch-1.1.0)
3. Open a browser (Safari or Chrome only) and go to

   file:///home/username/sencha-touch-1.1.0/examples/oreilly/index.html

If you want to navigate any other examples, point your browser to:

```
file:///home/username/sencha-touch-1.1.0/examples/
```

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the page > View Page Source > On the top you'll see the script files >

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../sencha-touch.js"></script> 
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="oreilly-all.js"></script> --> 

<!-- Application JS --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/index.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="src/Models.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/App.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/SessionList.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/SpeakerList.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/HtmlPage.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/SpeakerDetail.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/SessionDetail.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/LocationMap.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/AboutList.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/VideoList.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/TweetList.js"></script>
```

You need to basically download these one by one and then reference them manually in your local html file which you'll need to test.

That's the way to actually access the examples. However I would prefer you go through their screencasts, you'll get the source code for them easily from github.

e.g. For this screen cast: http://vimeo.com/15672696 , you can get the source from https://github.com/nelstrom/GeoTweets

Comment: Yes I tried setting up the files/paths locally like you have showed above...But it just does not work or show anything on screen...Is it necassary to access these via a local server setup and then try 127.0.0.1

Comment: if it's not showing anything it means it can't access the files correctly. Sencha initializes everything (including display elements) using Javascript. So if Javascript fails, you won't see anything. Try using Firebug (FireFox) or Javascript Console (Chrome) to see what error does it give.

Comment: Actually it is throwing a lot of errors..including Error: WebKitPoint is not defined
Source File: file:///D:/testing/sencha/sencha-touch.js
Line: 6

Comment: Which browser are you using? It will only work on webkit-based browsers i.e. Chrome or Safari.